# dynamic image path not showing in [style.background-image] property in Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7, encodeuricomponent

I am trying to use dynamic image path as background image in one of my Angular6 project.
I have tried using [style.background-image] & [style.background] even encodeURI to fix spaces in path also tried using *ngIF so that it renders after getting loaded.

Case 1:

imgPath is the absolute path, to which I am appending the path from JSON data.

**HTML code**

```
    <a routerLink="/article/{{news.id}}">        
      <img [style.background-image]="'url(' + imgPath + news.encodedImage.encocoded_primary_image + ')'">          
    </a>
```

**Component**

Checking images for spaces and other bracket using encodeURI() function

```
'encocoded_primary_image': encodeURI(res['primary_image']['file_path'])
```

**Output**

[Image comparison of article](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCpqa.png)

### As seen in the picture "s/Absorica%20(2).png" is having brackets, which might be causing the bug but not sure though.

**Other cases**

I have tried with `[style.background]` , `[ngStyle]` , changing image tag to div tag.

But i am not able to understand why few of the images are rendering and few are not rendering, though path is getting generated correctly, which I have confirmed by opening them in new tab.

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Can you please provide a Demo in StackBlitz. I Am not sure if im understanding everything right. Which files are not working and which are ? Is there a pattern ? The brackets should not really bother angular

Comment: @Joniras its solved now .. you can check below solution its working for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. In `background-image: url` accepts the string. You have to add your image path to a string.

`"'url(\'' + imgPath + news.encodedImage.encocoded_primary_image + '\')'"`

```html
<a routerLink="/article/{{news.id}}">
  <img [style.background-image]="'url(\'' + imgPath + news.encodedImage.encocoded_primary_image + '\')'">
</a>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image

https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/pr_background-image.asp

2. Try using escape() method but this method has been deprecated. Careful using this.

   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape

Comment: right .. escape() is deprecated and encodeURI() might ditch you in few of the special characters so better to make image path as string.

Answer (score 0):

don't use any ElementRef, DomSanitizer

in **component** :

```
img = '';
data(){       //image url -> if it comes from anywhere & any time
   this.img = 'http://img.....'
}
```

in **template**:
use in any supported tag

```
<div style="background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover;"
 [style.background-image]='"url(\"" + banner + "\")"'></div>
```

//or

```
<div style="background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover;"
 [style.background-image]="'url(\'' + banner + '\')'"></div>
```