# How to use angular loop variable in [style] of pFileUpload

Tags: angular, primeng

The part `[style.background-image]="'url('+ file.objectURL +')'"` doesn't seem to work and no error is returned. Using the variable **file** from **ng-template's let-file** works fine inside [src] of this line `<img *ngIf="file.type.startsWith('image')" [src]="file.objectURL>"` but doesn't seem to work inside `[style.background-image]`. Any help much appreciated. Thanks!

```
<ng-template let-file pTemplate="file">
   <div class="ui-fileupload-row">
      <div style="text-align: center;"> 
         <img *ngIf="file.type.startsWith('image')" [src]="file.objectURL" width="150"/> /** This works fine **/
         <i *ngIf="!file.type.startsWith('image')" class="pi pi-file"></i>
      </div>
      <div style="height: 50px">
         <div
            [style.background-image]="'url('+ file.objectURL +')'" /** This doesn't work **/
            [style.background-size]="'cover'"
            [style.width.px]="200"
            [style.height]="'inherit'"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
</ng-template>
```

file.objectURL contains blob:http://6hjqmn2.yyy.com:8014/27fffed1-5d30-49f1-bfee-935f56a2ec24

Comment: did you checked this question ?! 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53810678/dynamic-image-path-not-showing-in-style-background-image-property-in-angular-7

Comment: `file.objectURL` what does it contain ?, Can you please post the example value of this variable

Comment: Bad tagging. Please remove the one you don't use